# Adding song to Spotify playlist trhough API

Tags: api, spotify

I am willing to add a song to my Spotify playlist in python.

Here is my snippet:

```html
requests.get(
    'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/1166213676/playlists/0Lxegec43cvMTduXGxSZrJ/tracks',
    params={
        'uris':'spotify:track:0DZwrC4QQOYqpcxCeZzwDg'
    },
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)}
).json()
```

I have been trying to replicate this url format but still doesn't work.

```html
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/1166213676/playlists/0Lxegec43cvMTduXGxSZrJ/tracks?uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A3Id4IMrIZ1sHOB1XxPLH1I" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {my_token}"
```

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to GET instead of POST. Try replacing `requests.get` with `requests.post`.

You should definitely check out the "Spotipy" API wrapper though, which makes calling the Spotify API much easier. For example, this call would be:

```
sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, track_ids)
```